# How to query Active Record with method from another gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the acts_as_votable gem to allow my model Post to be voted on. It allows me to do things like @post.weighted_score to see the net amount of upvotes/downvotes for the post combined. How can I use this method in my posts_controller to query posts where the weighted score is say more than 5? I need to do this because I'd like to have a 'Trending' and 'Hot' page for posts, where posts need a certain amount of points to be shown there. Thanks

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching), you can add cached columns, including `cached_weighted_score`, and presumably you could query on those.

Answer (score 0):

You need joins with `votes_for` as `acts_as_votable` relations suggest,

```
Post.left_joins(:votes_for).group('id').having('SUM(IF(vote_flag = 1, 1, IF(vote_flag = 0, -1, 0))) > ?', 5)
```

This gives you top weighted score is more than 5